# Markdown report problem with image and results based in dynamic reactive objects

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'd like to create a markdown report using my `report.Rmd` file but I have two problems, first, the image is not found using (`title: <center> ![smille.jpg](smille.jpg) **Happy Dash** </center>`), despite smile image and `report.Rmd` is in the same directory, and another problem is that `R` operations (like `r unique(selectedvariable1()$DATA_S2)`) in the report using `reactive` objects doesn't work. In my example:

```
# Packages
library(shinythemes)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(anytime)
require(rmarkdown)
require(knitr)


# get AOI
download.file(
  "https://github.com/Leprechault/trash/raw/main/stands_example_v2.zip",
  zip_path <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")
)
unzip(zip_path, exdir = tempdir())

# Open the files
setwd(tempdir())
stands_ds <- read.csv("pred_target_stands.csv", sep=";") # Data set
stands_ds <- stands_ds %>%
  mutate(DATA_S2 = ymd(DATA_S2))
stands_ds$PEST<-c(rep("A",34),rep("B",225))

# Create the shiny dash
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("cosmo"),
  titlePanel(title="My Dash"),  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "selectedvariable0", "Type", choices = c(unique(stands_ds$PEST))),
      selectInput(inputId = "selectedvariable1", "Date",choices = NULL),
      selectInput(inputId = "selectedvariable2", "Project",choices = NULL),
      selectInput(inputId = "selectedvariable3", "Stand",choices = NULL),
      selectInput(inputId = "selectedvariable4", "ID-Unique",choices = NULL),
      downloadButton("download5", "Markdown Report",style = "margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px", class = "butt",style = "width:500px"),
      tags$head(tags$style(".butt{background-color:#034f84;} .butt{color: ##7CFC00;}"))
      
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("idSaida")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  
  selectedvariable0 <- reactive({
    filter(stands_ds, PEST == unique(stands_ds$PEST))
  })
  observeEvent(selectedvariable0(), {
    choices <- anytime::anydate(unique(selectedvariable0()$DATA_S2))
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "selectedvariable1", choices = choices) 
  })
  
  selectedvariable1 <- reactive({
    req(input$selectedvariable1)
    filter(selectedvariable0(), DATA_S2 == anytime::anydate(input$selectedvariable1))
  })
  observeEvent(selectedvariable1(), {
    choices <- unique(selectedvariable1()$PROJETO)
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "selectedvariable2", choices = choices)
  })
  
  selectedvariable2 <- reactive({
    req(input$selectedvariable2)
    filter(selectedvariable0(), PROJETO == input$selectedvariable2)
  })
  observeEvent(selectedvariable2(), {
    choices <- unique(selectedvariable2()$CD_TALHAO)
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "selectedvariable3", choices = choices)
  })
  
  selectedvariable3 <- reactive({
    req(input$selectedvariable3)
    filter(selectedvariable0(), CD_TALHAO == input$selectedvariable3)
  })
  observeEvent(selectedvariable3(), {
    choices <- unique(selectedvariable3()$ID_UNIQUE)
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "selectedvariable4", choices = choices)
  })
  selectedvariable4 <- reactive({
    req(input$selectedvariable4)
    filter(selectedvariable0(), ID_UNIQUE == input$selectedvariable4)
  })
  
  # Report creation
  output$download5 <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "report.html",
    content = function(file) {
      # identify the folders
      current.folder <- getwd()
      new.folder <- tempdir()
      # find the files that you want
      list.of.files <- list.files(current.folder, "report.Rmd$")
      # copy the files to the new folder
      file.copy(list.of.files, new.folder)
      tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd")
      file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
      rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                        params = params,
                        envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
      )
    }
  )
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
##

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  
  selectedvariable0 <- reactive({
    filter(stands_ds, PEST == unique(stands_ds$PEST))
  })
  observeEvent(selectedvariable0(), {
    choices <- anytime::anydate(unique(selectedvariable0()$DATA_S2))
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "selectedvariable1", choices = choices) 
  })
  
  selectedvariable1 <- reactive({
    req(input$selectedvariable1)
    filter(selectedvariable0(), DATA_S2 == anytime::anydate(input$selectedvariable1))
  })
  observeEvent(selectedvariable1(), {
    choices <- unique(selectedvariable1()$PROJETO)
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "selectedvariable2", choices = choices)
  })
  
  selectedvariable2 <- reactive({
    req(input$selectedvariable2)
    filter(selectedvariable0(), PROJETO == input$selectedvariable2)
  })
  observeEvent(selectedvariable2(), {
    choices <- unique(selectedvariable2()$CD_TALHAO)
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "selectedvariable3", choices = choices)
  })
  
  selectedvariable3 <- reactive({
    req(input$selectedvariable3)
    filter(selectedvariable0(), CD_TALHAO == input$selectedvariable3)
  })
  observeEvent(selectedvariable3(), {
    choices <- unique(selectedvariable3()$ID_UNIQUE)
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "selectedvariable4", choices = choices)
  })
  selectedvariable4 <- reactive({
    req(input$selectedvariable4)
    filter(selectedvariable0(), ID_UNIQUE == input$selectedvariable4)
  })

  # Report creation
  output$download5 <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "report.html",
    content = function(file) {
      # identify the folders
      current.folder <- getwd()
      new.folder <- tempdir()
      # find the files that you want
      list.of.files <- list.files(current.folder, "report.Rmd$")
      # copy the files to the new folder
      file.copy(list.of.files, new.folder)
      tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd")
      file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
      rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                        params = params,
                        envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
      )
    }
  )
 }
shinyApp(ui, server)
##
```

My Rmd file report.Rmd (inside my zip file too)

```
---
title: <center> ![smille.jpg](smille.jpg) **Happy Dash** </center>
author: "by me"
date: " `r Sys.Date()` "
output: html_document
---
  
## Collected reactive data information
Total data: `r unique(selectedvariable1()$DATA_S2)`
```

Please, any help me fix these two issues?

Comment: I guess you may need `runtime: shiny`

Comment: Thanks, @akrun, but exactly where in the code a need to put `runtime: shiny`?

Comment: It should be in the yaml, i.e. after the ouptut line you can add `runtime: shiny`

Comment: In the downloadHandler you can store the variable `unique(selectedvariable1()$DATA_S2)` in `params` to pass it to the RMarkdown document. For example see this RMarkdown tutorial: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-6.html

Comment: Thanks, @akrun and @baroque problem with reactive objects solved, but now the problem with the image remains and the output is: `Error in : pandoc document conversion failed with error 99`

Comment: The error is just if `![smille.jpg](smille.jpg)` in the `title: <center> ![smille.jpg](smille.jpg) **Happy Dash** </center>` in the yaml, after ```Total data: `r unique(selectedvariable1()$DATA_S2)``` no problem and the images is corrected printed.